# Autofac resolve all EventHandlers of abstract base class

Tags: c#, autofac

Hi Some how I cannot find the answer to this problem:
I Have event handler ala:

```
public class MyEvenHandler : EventHandler<MyEvent>
```

Where EventHandler is an abstract class

```
 public abstract class EventHandler<TEvent> : IEventHandler<TEvent>
    where TEvent : IDomainEvent
```

And

```
public interface IEventHandler<in TEvent> : IEventHandler where TEvent : IDomainEvent
{
    bool Handles(IDomainEvent @event);
    void Handle(TEvent @event);
    Task HandleAsync(TEvent @event);
}
```

I Register with autofac like this:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterSource(new ContravariantRegistrationSource());
```

...

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(commandsAssemblies)
            .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(EventHandler<>))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerRequest();
```

Now I want to resolve all eventhandlers and register them with a messageDispatcher class

```
var handlers = e.Context.Resolve<IEnumerable<IEventHandler<IDomainEvent>>>().ToList();

var handlers2 = e.Context.Resolve<IEnumerable<IEventHandler<PolicyCreated>>>().ToList();
```

the handlers variable is empty...
handlers2 resolves correctly. But I would like to resolve all handlers genericly

the messageDispatcher (eventDispathcer) look like this:

```
public class EventDispatcher : IEventDispatcher
{
    private readonly IList<IEventHandler> _eventHandlers = new List<IEventHandler>();

    public virtual void RegisterEventHandler(IEventHandler eventHandler)
    {
        _eventHandlers.Add(eventHandler);
    }

    public virtual IMessageResults Publish<TEvent>(TEvent @event) where TEvent : IDomainEvent
    {
        var result = new MessageResults();
        var handlers = _eventHandlers;

        if (handlers == null)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("No event handlers for event {0} ", typeof(TEvent)));

            result.AddResult(new MessageResult(true));
            return result;
        }

        foreach (var eventHandler in handlers.Where(h => h.Handles(@event as IDomainEvent)))
        {
            eventHandler.Handle(@event);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public int EventHandlerCount
    {
        get
        {
            return _eventHandlers.Count();
        }
    }
}
```

To summarize goals:

1. use assembly scanning
2. resolve to IEnumerable of implementations of EventHandler

Answer (score 1):

You want to cast `MyEvenHandler` to `IEventHandler<IDomainEvent>`

If we try the following code :

```
MyEventHandler handler = new MyEventHandler();
IEventHandler<IDomainEvent> e = (IEventHandler<IDomainEvent>)handler;
```

The CLR will throw an `InvalidCastException` because `IEventHandler<TDomainEvent>` is not covariant. If the CLR allow this kind of conversion, it would mean that the following code would compile :

```
MyEventHandler handler = new MyEventHandler();
IEventHandler<IDomainEvent> e = (IEventHandler<IDomainEvent>)handler;
e.Handle(new MyEvent2());
```

How the CLR should execute it ?  e expect a `MyEvent` and not a `MyEvent2`

If you want a list of all your eventHandlers you will have to introduce a base interface

```
public interface IEventHandler
{
    Boolean Handles(IDomainEvent @event);
}
public interface IEventHandler<TEvent> : IEventHandler 
    where TEvent : IDomainEvent
{
    void Handle(TEvent @event);
    Task HandleAsync(TEvent @event);
}
```

And register eventHandlers as `IEventHandler`

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Program).Assembly)
       .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IEventHandler<>))
       .As<IEventHandler>();
```

Using this registration, you will be able to resolve `IEventHandler` and `IEventHandler<MyEvent>`

```
var genericHandlers = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IEventHandler>>();
var handlers = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IEventHandler<MyEvent>>>();
```

By the way, instead of having a dependency on `IEnumerable<IEventHandler>`, `messageDispatcher` may have a dependency on `ILifetimeScope` and when it needs eventHandlers, it will be able to resolve them :

```
public class EventDispatcher
{
    private readonly ILifetimeScope _scope;

    public EventDispatcher(ILifetimeScope scope)
    {
        this._scope = scope;
    }

    public virtual IMessageResults Publish<TEvent>(TEvent @event) where TEvent : IDomainEvent
    {
        var result = new MessageResults();
        var handlers = this._scope.Resolve<IEnumerable<IEventHandler<TEvent>>>().ToList();

        if (!handlers.Any())
        {
            Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("No event handlers for event {0} ", typeof(TEvent)));

            result.AddResult(new MessageResult(true));
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var eventHandler in handlers.Where(h => h.Handles(@event as IDomainEvent)))
            {
                eventHandler.Handle(@event);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public int EventHandlerCount
    {
        get
        {
            // not tested 
            var handlerCount = this._scope.ComponentRegistry
                                          .Registrations
                                          .Where(r => r.Services
                                                     .OfType<IServiceWithType>()
                                                     .Any(swt => swt.ServiceType.IsGenericType
                                                                 && swt.ServiceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEventHandler<>)))
                                          .Count();
            return handlerCount;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT** : This answer was before the edit with full interface declaration

If `IEventHandler<TEvent>` doesn't accept any `TEvent` in methods, you have to convert your `IEventHandler<TEvent>` to a covariant interface using the `out` modifier (see [out (Generic Modifier) (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487(v=vs.140).aspx) for more information).

```
public interface IEventHandler<out TEvent>
    where TEvent : DomainEventBase
{ }
```

Using this, the CLR will be able to cast `MyEventHandler` to `IEventHandler<DomainEventBase>`.

Then, you have to tell *Autofac* that your types is `IEventHandler<DomainEventBase>` by registering them as `IEventHandler<DomainEventBase>`

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(Program).Assembly)
       .As<IEventHandler<DomainEventBase>>();
```

You can now get all your eventHandlers using

```
container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IEventHandler<DomainEventBase>>>()
```

By the way, the `ContravariantRegistrationSource` is not needed in your case.

Comment: Thx for answering! IEventHandler take TEvent as an input parameter in its Handle method so it cannot be declared as covariant. I have added the full declaration now

Comment: @ChristianJohansen see my edits. BTW could you share your messageDispatcher ? There may be something to do

Comment: Sure! I Have added the code for messageDispathcer (EventDispatcher) now. My Work around Currently is to Register and Resolve as simple non Generic  interface IEventHandler limiting my self to only working with interfaces.

Comment: @ChristianJohansen In your case I would add a dependency on `ILifetimeScope` on the `EventDispatcher` class. It would then be possible to resolve the final type in your `Publish` method.

Comment: So during tests I would have to Mock ILifeTimeScope ? Mybe that would not be to hard. But I would prefer not inject it.

Comment: @ChristianJohansen if you don't want to rely on ILifetimeScope, you can create a `IEventHandlerFactory` with a `GetEventHandler<TDomainEvent>` method, you will have one implementation with a ILifetimeScope dependency and another one for your test.

Answer (score 0):

1、create an empty interface without generic

```
public interface IEventHandler{}
```

2、your IEventHandler should implement this interface

```
IEventHandler<TEvent>:IEventHandler
```

3、try resolve use this interface

```
e.Context.Resolve<IEnumerable<IEventHandler>>()
```

this way may not the best